# Opening an outside executable file with Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#

I keep getting the NotImplementedException error when trying to have my launcher for games open an outside executable with this code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Process.Start("C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/osu!");

        }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs     e)
    {

    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}

internal class CustomWindow
{
    private string v;

    public CustomWindow(string v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    internal void Show()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}



internal class Window1 : Form
{
}

internal class Process
{
    public object StartInfo { get; internal set; }

    internal static void Start(string v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
    }
```

NOTE: I just started learning C# today so please try to be patient w/ me.

Comment: Which line of code causes the exception?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to launch the external app, please consider the following,

1. Give the absolute path of particular exe including filename with extension
2. Add the parameter/option to mention the startup path for particular exe
3. If you are importing dll, which is managed code you are add them through "Add Reference" option
4. If you want use unmanaged code, use dllImport option.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
internal static void Start(string v)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

you have code that intentionally throws a NotImplementedException. C# already has this functionality, you don't need to create a class for it. Delete yours and use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Just delete your process class unless you plan to do something special with it.

Comment: It automatically adds that. :l It has a red line underneath Process.Start("PATH"). :l

Comment: It automatically adds what? The NotImplementedException? Yes, it will until you delete that line and specify what you want the method to do. But you're trying to add functionality that already exists. Process.Start is a .net feature, you don't need to make a class for it. Delete your class and it will work as desired.

Comment: I deleted that line. How do I specify what I want the method to do? And how do I delete my class?

Comment: Here's what's going on. You implemented a new class called Process inside of the same class you are declaring it from. Process is meant to be a .net class, you don't have to make it, that's the beautiful thing about .net, it does a lot of stuff for you. If you want to simply start a process and not worry about it, delete everything from internal class Process { until the very last } and then run it, and your process will start.

Comment: I don't get what I'm supposed to delete though. :l

Comment: That works... somewhat. I want this to open up the application however it is only opening File Explorer to that path.